# In Android proguard java script function not call on webview button click

Tags: javascript, android, webview

After using pro guard java script interface method not working in release apk and same code working perfectly in development mode.
please help where i am wrong!

Code is below

```
public class Tab_Login extends Fragment
{

    View rootView;
    MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface;
    static WebView myWebView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Login.html");
        myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(getActivity());
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "Android");

    }

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        Context mContext;

        public MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c)
        {
            this.mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void loginBuy()
        {
            try
            {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Method call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

For proguard code below

```
    // open this line
    proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

// add these line
-keep public class com.xyz.Tab_Login.MyJavaScriptInterface

-keep public class * implements com.xyz.Tab_Login.MyJavaScriptInterface

-keepclassmembers class com.xyz.Tab_Login.MyJavaScriptInterface { 
  <fields>;
    <methods>; 
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface.
```

Comment: @PankajKumar i have post my both code please check

Answer (score 0):

Use below line and check

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i have already applying this code but still not working

Comment: @Nirav You should include an explanation for your answer, rather than just here is the code